# Using JBoss to connect EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I use a JBoss server to host my EJB.

The server is started, I see the main page when I go to localhost:8080 *(Welcome to AS 7, Your JBoss Application Server 7 is running.)*

On my client project, I try to connect like this :

```
    private static Calculette lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator() throws NamingException {    
    final Context context = new InitialContext();
    context.addToEnvironment("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    context.addToEnvironment("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    context.addToEnvironment("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:8080");

    return (Calculette) context.lookup("ejb/stateless/calculette");
}
```

I go this error message when I run it :

```
Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:8080 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server localhost:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]]
```

I try with a jndi.properties but I got error I don't understand, when I put the parameter directly on the context it's ok ..

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI lookup works on a different port. By default you will have to use:

```
 Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
 jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
 jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
 // create a context passing these properties
 Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
```

Be aware, that for different JBoss/Wildfly versions different approaches exists.

See also: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project

Comment: Thanks ! I think it's better, I added the xio dependency and now I have this error :/ I can't find why..

`INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]`

Comment: Is your client running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes server and client is on the same machine

Comment: I moving from JBoss 7 to Wildfly 18 and I got this error : 
`Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [remote://localhost:4447]`

It's look better, even it's didn't work ..

Comment: As I said: There is a couple of years between AS 7 and Wildfly 18 and you have to use a little bit different approach (including other ports and url) . See e.g. here https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/18.0.x/ejb-remote